# Regarding use of xsl:choose

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file in which their is unit mentioned.

```
    <RQ>2.000</RQ>
```

I need to check in my xsl file whether in the value their is a + or - sign. If their is no sign then the default will be + sign.
I was writing it with xsl:choose element but it was not working out.

Comment: There is no xsd associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an **xsl:choose**, you could do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="RQ">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="number() != number()">NaN</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="number() >= 0">+</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>-</xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This would also cope with the element not containing a number. Alternatively, you could make better use of template matching, and eliminate the need for an **xsl:choose** altogether.

```
<xsl:template match="RQ[number() != number()]">NaN</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RQ[number() >= 0]">+</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RQ">-</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It worked like this -

<xsl:template name="amount">
        <xsl:param name="sign"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($sign,'-')">
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
Call this template in xsl element node.

<ABC>
    <xsl:call-template name="amount">
    <xsl:with-param name="sign" select="normalize-space(RQ/RQ)"/> <--Xpath specified-->
    </xsl:call-template>
</ABC>

Comment: Can you amend your question with this information, as that will makes things much clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**If it can be guaranteed that `RQ` is a valid representation of a number, then just use:**

```
substring('+-', 2 - (RQ > 0), 1)
```

**A complete demo**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
       "substring('+-', 2 - (RQ > 0), 1)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to this XML document:**

```
<RQ>-2.000</RQ>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
-
```

**and when applied to this document:**

```
<RQ>2.000</RQ>
```

**again produces the correct result:**

```
+
```

**If desired, this one-liner XPath expression can be encapsulated in a separate named template to be called from various places in the code -- like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="sign">
       <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="RQ"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="sign">
   <xsl:param name="pNum"/>

     <xsl:value-of select=
       "substring('+-', 2 - (RQ > 0), 1)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**But notice that the call to the named template occupies three lines while simply using the one liner takes, well, one line**.